# переход на якорь под спойлером slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

на странице есть спойлеры такого вида:

```
<div class="spoiler closed">
<div class="title">
<div class="title_h3">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="contents">
Content
Content
<a name="anchor"></a> Text
</div>
```

спойлер включаю вот таким скриптом:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
$(".closed").toggleClass("show");
$(".title").click(function(){
 $(this).parent().toggleClass("show").children("div.contents").slideToggle("medium");
 if ($(this).parent().hasClass("show"))
    $(this).children(".title_h3").css("background","#2b2b2b");}
 else $(this).children(".title_h3").css("background","#2b2b2b");}
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

как сделать чтобы можно было придти с любой внешней страницы по ссылке типа /#anchor на якорь в контенте, который спрятан под спойлером, спойле при этом должен соответственно открыться
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался: вместо якоря использую атрибут name:

```
<a name="ets"></a>
```

далее скриптом ищется элемент, имя которого берётся из хеша ссылки
далее ищем родительский объект и делаем клик по объекту, который идёт перед ним:

```
$('a[name=' + window.location.hash.replace('#','') + ']').closest('.contents').prev('.title').click();
```

Comment: А надо ``id``...